# Classic SQL Server Operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, query-optimization

I am assuming this is the most common scenario with everyone who is working with SQL Server.

Scenario:

I have these tables `tabSRC_A(id,date,data1)`, `tabSRC_B(id,Date,data2)` and `tabDEST`

Now my task is to get the data from `tableSRC_A`, `tableSRC_B` apply some filtering and cleanup on them and insert them into `tabDEST`.

I am doing this using the following code

```
insert into tabDest(id, Date, Data1, Data2)
   Select id, date, Data1, Data2 
   from tabSRC_A A 
   inner join tabSRC_B B on A.id = B.id and A.date = B.date
   where not exists 
             (select * from tabDest Dest 
              where Dest.id = B.id and Dest.date = B.date)
```

and I am updating if already exists

Is this the best solution for this operation?

The size of the tables are 10 million rows each

I was also thinking about creating a view with surrogate key and perform a check based on the id instead of checking every row using the above method

Something like this

```
 insert into tabDest(id, Date, Data1, Data2)
    Select id, date, Data1, Data2 
    from view_Created_From_TabA_TabB_adding_a_SurrogateKey_Kid SV
    where SV.Kid > select (max(id) from tabDest)
```

I am assuming this would be much faster.

Please guide me with any suggestions you have.

(I'm using SQL Server 2000, I know its very old)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a LEFT join to detect not exists?

```
insert into tabDest(id, Date, Data1, Data2)
   Select id, date, Data1, Data2 
   from tabSRC_A A 
   inner join tabSRC_B B on A.id = B.id and A.date = B.date
   LEFT JOIN tabDest Dest 
   ON Dest.id = B.id and Dest.date = B.date
WHERE
   Dest.id is null
```

Comment: In this case a left join may be worse since you would not expect a null id. http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

Comment: @Jeff O. I certainly acknowledge that it may not be better, which I why I wrote "have you tried...", but there's always a possibility that there's some variable that Quassnoi's experiments didn't consider so its worth a try. Also id isn't the only field being joined on so there's the potential that it could be null.

Answer (score 0):

That solution you have provide not bad, you could try this:

```
insert into tabDest(id, Date, Data1, Data2)
   Select A.id, A.date, Data1, Data2 
   from tabSRC_A A 
   inner join tabSRC_B B on A.id = B.id and A.date = B.date
   left join tabDest D.id = B.id and d.date = b.date
   where d is null;
```

The difference is that the sub-query will be executer once for each row, and in this case the left join will be done once but looking on the size of the table this will also be slow and the difference might be slight.

The creation of the view seams to be redundant, because generally they are not faster than query, the idea with id is good but in your case also date have some role in the identification. This leads me to conclude that you can not use that comparison and you can have two same ids with different time.

In case when id is unique you can use this statement

```
insert into tabDest(id, Date, Data1, Data2)
   Select A.id, A.date, Data1, Data2 
   from tabSRC_A A 
   inner join tabSRC_B B on A.id = B.id and A.date = B.date
   where A.id > (SELECT max(d.id) FROM Dest d);
```

What else you can do?

If You have possibility to add once column to table A with default value 0, then you could use a stored procedure for migration, you selection to insert only those columns that have value 0 (not use null) and then you set to them 1. Using this solution you will no scan full table.